# In GWT, which javascript function run when you click on a button?

Tags: gwt

GWT auto generate the JavaScript code.

I could not understand the generated code event mechanism.
for instance, which function run when I click on a button?

I would love to see the javascript that GWT generates for button with explanations

Comment: Why do you need to know this?

Comment: I am using a tool that does static analysis to javascript files, and I can't figure out the results on files that pretty JS files that GWT generated.

Comment: Then why do you need to do analysis on them?

Comment: I am playing with SCA tools for javascript

Answer (score 1):

For event handling, GWT attaches a `EventListener` (generally, your widget) as an expando property (called `__listener`) of the elements. The events are then all handled by a single *dispatch* method that looks at the `__listener` expando of the event's target and dispatches the event to it. Of course, the dispatch method does a bit more (event previewing, entry/finally scheduled commands, etc.)

This *dance* is (or at least was) required to avoid memory leaks in browsers (mainly IE). You can find more details in the GWT wiki: https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/DomEventsAndMemoryLeaks

Comment: it will be super awesome if you can show a simple code snippet, I can't find such a thing in the auto-generated code..

Comment: See https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/user/src/com/google/gwt/user/client/impl/DOMImplTrident.java (implementation for IE), https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/user/src/com/google/gwt/user/client/impl/DOMImpl.java#130 (where the `__listener` expando is set), and https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/user/src/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Widget.java#330 (where the widget registers itself as a `__listener`)

Comment: Compile a small app with `-draftCompile` and `-style PRETTY` and look for these things in the output.

Answer (score 0):

When you develop in GWT, you don't care about JavaScript.

You should look at the **Java** code, and search for a function that handles the click event for your button.

Comment: well, I know, yet I do care about the javascript, I am trying to understand the auto generated code...

Answer (score 0):

When you compile the code `Compiler` will generate the autoamted `Javascript` functions ...And that too in compressed  (thats depends on your compile type).

It is very hard to find the corresponding function and widget id because those are `generated` by `compiler`  ..So its better to debug  your `gwt` code is hosted mode ..

Even you want to read the generated code while compiling give the compilation type to

`DETAILED`, which improves on `PRETTY` with even more detail (such as very verbose variable names)

Still [more](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/1.6/FAQ_DebuggingAndCompiling) details available here .

Comment: I know, yet I do care about the javascript, I am trying to understand the auto generated code, if you can answer what's going on before the minimization and obfuscation that could be great.

Comment: put the compilation mode PRETTY, which makes the output readable to a human ..and DETAILED, which improves on PRETTY with even more detail (such as very verbose variable names)

Comment: I did that, but I could not still figure out which function a generic button is calling.. :-(

Comment: I'm informed that its just human readable  not understandable :(

Answer (score 0):

You should use GWT Compiler options `STYLE` whenever you need to understand the GWT's output js. GWT by default compresses and obfuscates the javascript output as it uses **OBF** as default value for STYLE.

To prevent compression and obfuscation you can use **PRETTY** or **DETAILED** as the parameter to STYLE argument.

**NOTE:** You should always use OBF mode for production as it ensures smallest bandwidth usage along with obfuscation.

**Reference** - https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCompilingAndDebugging#DevGuideCompilerOptions

[image]